# Odd add and remove children behaviors AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright, so this frame, you dodge asteroids, and if you hit a large one, it destroys you and you go to a different frame, however you have the option to move back to the previously mentioned frame. Sometimes when I retry the level, when I come back, some of the asteroids have been left there , like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfzid.jpg also, it seems that sometimes more asteroids appear on reload of that scene than there should be. Here's the code:

```
var speedAgainX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
var speedAgainY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
var speedAgainX1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
var speedAgainY1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
var speedAgainX2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
var speedAgainY2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
var speedAgainX3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
var speedAgainY3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);

var nCount1:Number = -0;

 timer_Text1.text = nCount1.toString();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,massCollect);
function massCollect(e:Event){
if(Cosmo.hitTestObject(Asteroid5)){
   removeChild(Asteroid5);
   nCount1++;
   timer_Text1.text = nCount1.toString();

  addChild(Asteroid5);
  Asteroid5.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid5.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid5.x = Asteroid5.x + speedAgainX;
   Asteroid5.y = Asteroid5.y + speedAgainY;
if (Asteroid5.x > 1100 || Asteroid5.x < -100)
{
    speedAgainX = -speedAgainX;
}
}

if(Cosmo.hitTestObject(Asteroid6)){
   removeChild(Asteroid6);
   nCount1++;
   timer_Text1.text = nCount1.toString();

  addChild(Asteroid6);
  Asteroid6.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid6.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid6.x = Asteroid6.x + speedAgainX1;
   Asteroid6.y = Asteroid6.y + speedAgainY1;
if (Asteroid6.x > 1100 || Asteroid6.x < -100)
{
    speedAgainX1 = -speedAgainX1;
}
}

if(Cosmo.hitTestObject(Asteroid7)){
   removeChild(Asteroid7);
   nCount1++;
   timer_Text1.text = nCount1.toString();

  addChild(Asteroid7);
  Asteroid7.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid7.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid7.x = Asteroid7.x + speedAgainX2;
   Asteroid7.y = Asteroid7.y + speedAgainY2;
if (Asteroid7.x > 1100 || Asteroid7.x < -100)
{
    speedAgainX2 = -speedAgainX2;
}
}

if(Cosmo.hitTestObject(Asteroid8)){
   removeChild(Asteroid8);
   nCount1++;
   timer_Text1.text = nCount1.toString();

  addChild(Asteroid8);
  Asteroid8.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid8.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid8.x = Asteroid8.x + speedAgainX3;
   Asteroid8.y = Asteroid8.y + speedAgainY3;
if (Asteroid8.x > 1100 || Asteroid8.x < -100)
{
    speedAgainX3 = -speedAgainX3;
}
}

if (Cosmo.hitTestObject(Deathroid1)){
    gotoAndStop(352, "Scene 1");

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,massCollect);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,massGain);
    removeChild(Asteroid5);
    removeChild(Asteroid6);
    removeChild(Asteroid7);
    removeChild(Asteroid8);
}
if (Cosmo.hitTestObject(Deathroid2)){
    gotoAndStop(352, "Scene 1");
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,massCollect);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,massGain);

    removeChild(Asteroid5);
    removeChild(Asteroid6);
    removeChild(Asteroid7);
    removeChild(Asteroid8);


}

if(nCount1 == 10){
    gotoAndStop(351, "Scene 1");
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,massCollect);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,massGain);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This chunk:

```
if(Cosmo.hitTestObject(Asteroid6)){
   removeChild(Asteroid6);
   nCount1++;
   timer_Text1.text = nCount1.toString();

  addChild(Asteroid6);
  Asteroid6.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid6.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
   Asteroid6.x = Asteroid6.x + speedAgainX1;
   Asteroid6.y = Asteroid6.y + speedAgainY1;
if (Asteroid6.x > 1100 || Asteroid6.x < -100)
{
    speedAgainX1 = -speedAgainX1;
}
}
```

You're basically recreating Asteroid6 when Cosmo collides with it. I think it's just an issue of bracket placement, though. Same goes for the rest.

Also, your whole code is a bit of a mess. You should look into arrays so you can manage your asteroids better.

Comment: Hmm, I'll give that a try. Sorry the code's messy, I'm a beginner, and I do really need to look into classes and arrays, and other code organization methods.

Comment: Also, would the bracketing lead to the asteroids being frozen on the other frame like that? could it be an issue with animation on the timeline? Note, this is all done on 1 timeline in 1 scene, and the code I posted is from my actions layer, not Layer 1.

Comment: @user2072135 If you're using keyframes, then it is an issue. I'm not too experienced with timeline programming since I find using classes better in the long run, but did you stick the instances on the stage or did you use `addChild()` to add them when the SWF starts?

Comment: Well, this is a bit complicated. I have the original asteroids on the stage when the frame starts, then I have code that says if you hit one, it should removeChild and then addChild (The same asteroid) at a random place.

Comment: @user2072135 Ah, I see now. You can always just take out the whole `removeChild(Asteroid6)` and `addChild(Asteroid6)` since it's redundant.

Comment: Haha, how didn't I think of that before? I guess I was over complicating things. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2072135 No problemo. Just be sure to close this question.